# How to write MySQL stored procedure for adding a range of records between two dates

Tags: mysql, date, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in MySQL that will receive two dates. A from date and a two date. I've written stored procedures before but I'm stumped as to where to start with this.

How can I code a stored procedure that, when it received 20170101 and 20170110 it adds the following to a table
20170101
20170102
20170103
20170104
20170105
20170106
20170107
20170108
20170109
20170110

I don't simply want to add one to each value as they are dates and 20170132 doesn't exist in reality.

Thank you everyone

Comment: use a combination of str_to_data and date_add

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (field_name VARCHAR(255)); 

DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test1`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`(
    IN pi_date_from     DATE,
    IN pi_date_to       DATE
    )
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    SET @countRecordToAdd   = 0;
    SET @i          = 0;
    SET @query      = 'INSERT INTO table_name (field_name) VALUES ';

    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(pi_date_to, pi_date_from)
    INTO
        @countRecordToAdd
    ;

    IF @countRecordToAdd > 0
    THEN
        label1: LOOP
            SET @query  = CONCAT(
                            @query,
                            " (date_add(\"", pi_date_from, "\", INTERVAL ", @i, " DAY)),"
                        );
            SET @i = @i + 1;
            IF @i <= @countRecordToAdd THEN ITERATE label1;END IF;

            LEAVE label1;

        END LOOP label1;

        PREPARE stmt    FROM TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM @query);
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```